# Messaging using Python Socket(Threading)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chat

I was working with Socket and threading library but threading does not work as well as i expected. For e.g. when you send a message from server to client message wont be appear, but i you send a message after that from client to server the message(came from server before) will be appear.

Here is the code for Server side

```
import socket
from threading import Thread as t

port = 8000
ip = "localhost"  # or your ip

s = socket.socket()

s.bind((ip,port))

s.listen()

c, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected")

def se():
        while True:
                msg = input("Your msg: ")
                c.send(msg.encode())

def re():
        while True:
                msg = c.recv(1024)
                print(msg.decode())

t1 = t(target=se)
t2 = t(target=re)


t1.start()
t2.start()
```

and here is code for client

```
import socket
from threading import Thread as t

port = 8000
ip = "localhost"   # or your ip

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((ip,port))
print("Connected")

def se():
        while True:
                msg = input("Your msg: ")
                s.send(msg.encode())

def re():
        while True:
                msg = s.recv(1024)
                print(msg.decode())

t1 = t(target=se)
t2 = t(target=re)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

How can i fix it(i mean i send a message to client and he can see that and when he sends me something i can see that too, with any order and arrangement)

[image: When i send hey from client side it must appear on server side but as you can see that is not happening]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug (as far as I understand what it is). Messages entered on either side are received and printed immediately on the other side. Is there other code in your application that's not included here?

Comment: The problem is here! The message from other side does not show up.It shows up right after you enter and send your message to other side

Comment: Are you saying that you have to press the "Enter" key before your message is sent? If that's your issue, then this has nothing to do with sockets or threading. The [`input` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) in Python waits until the user enters a _line_ of text. So yes, you have to press "Enter" before `input` returns.

Comment: I mean when your are using whats app or other messengers. You can see the message from the other person without sending anything. But in this case you cant see that! You have to send something and then the message from the other side will appear, otherwise you cant see anything and its just a simple socket code without threading.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're describing. When I copy and run your code, I can enter a message on either side, press enter, and the message appears on the other terminal. I do not need to first send a message in order to receive one. Please include the exact behavior you see and the exact behavior you'd _like_ to see. And please make sure that you have included all relevant code, to make sure that you're not running something different from one of us trying to help.

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220816/discussion-between-bnaecker-and-joseph-a).